# Promise {<pending>} with PromiseState "fulfilled" with forEach and async

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am currently working in Ext JS, although that really should not matter. The code is simple: I have `myFunc` which constructs a `myArray`. Using `forEach` to loop through `myArray`, I call `getDescription` on each array element. `getDescription` is an async function that triggers an API call to get some resource.

`elementDescription` - the result of calling `getDescription` on each element of `myArray` ends up being a

`Promise {<pending>}  __proto__: Promise [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled" [[PromiseResult]]: "correct value from the API"`

I'm quite new to promises, and I feel like the nested `forEach` along with the `async` syntax is somehow screwing with the code.

My code is as follows:

```js
myFunc: function() {
    //some initial procedures 

    myArray.forEach(element => {
        var elementDescription = getDescription(element.Property).then(function(result) {return result})
        console.log(elementDescription)
    })

    // some more procedures
}

getDescription: async function (elementProperty) {
    var description = ""
    var apiResponse = await someWayToTriggerGetRequest()
    apiResponse.forEach(item => {description += item.content)
    return description;
}
```

What is going on? **Why am I getting a pending promise?**

Comment: `then` returns the result wrapped in a promise: `elementDescription` is also a promise. You need to do `elementDescription.then(data => console.log(data)` to see *fulfilled* response.

Comment: I see; yes, using `elementDescription.then(data => console.log(data)`, I can see the data. But could I set `elementDescription` to `data`? I tried `
elementDescription.then(data => {
    if (data) {
        elementDescription = data;
    }
}` But it does not work...